# Qt Using a pre-existing model with QAbstractItemModel

Tags: qt

I have an existing object model containing a variety of properties, and I would like to either wrap it or refactor a collection of them into a `QAbstractItemModel` so that I can easily display the properties as tables. Given how modelling works in Qt, I'm a bit confused.

From what I understand, `QAbstractItemModel` requires having an underlying data structure such as a vector or map and overriding the interfaced functions to abstract it into a table. However, it appears that if I wanted to take an existing model I would have to hard-code each column specifically to a particular object property.

For instance, say my model is the following:

```
class Example {
   QString exampleName;
   QPixmap exampleImage;
   QString exampleDescription;
   uint exampleSequenceId;
   uint exampleExpiration;
}
```

If I wanted to implement it as a `QAbstractItemModel` class, I would have to override the necessary functions and have a hard coding that would designate `exampleName` as column 0, `exampleImage` as column 1, and so on.

Surely there is a cleaner way of doing this? I would like to avoid as much hardcoding as possible in the event that the model is changed in the future. It seems like a code smell to have static designations for each column, and even more of a code smell to have a model backed by a vector, although I understand that it's done to maintain uniformity.

Am I approaching this right? The only solid examples I've seen involve a pair of strings such as Qt's TreeView example. None of them seem to delve into implementing multi-column object models.

Comment: I think in such a language as C++ lacking any reflection facilities you can't really avoid the hardcoding. You might want to look into [Qt property system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) to see if you can use its rather minimalistic reflection facilities to make things generic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would be interested with [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) not QTableView. QTableWidget is item-based widget so you don't need a model.